# CTRL + C not working when script run from boot

Tags: raspbian, boot

I'm running a python script from boot on my Raspberry Pi B running Raspbian. I set the `raspi-config` so it is console auto logon. And I have the script that I want to run from boot into `/etc/profile` and I added to the very last line of that file `sudo python /link/to/script.py`. The script runs absolutely perfect. However, when I come to terminate it, it does not always work.

I am pressing `CTRL + C` and `CTRL + Z` to try and exit but it doesn't always work. It just prints `^C` or `^Z` into the terminal.

The script I am running sits in a `while True` loop as it is sending data from a sensor and I need it to be sending the data all of the time.

**This is the script**

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
import requests
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import signal

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)

ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo=17, trigger=4, max_distance=4)
print (ultrasonic.distance)
def connection_check():
    try:
        requests.get("http://google.com", timeout=1)
        return True
    except:
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(20,GPIO.HIGH)
        #print("CONNECTION LOST...")
        #print("RETRYING...")
        pass
    return False

while True:
    if connection_check() == True:
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(20, GPIO.LOW)
        #print (ultrasonic.distance)
        distance = ultrasonic.distance
        publish.single("test/message",distance, hostname="172.18.65.XXX")
```

Has anyone had an issue like this and how do I get around it, sometimes it can take upwards of 10 minutes to try and terminate the script.

Comment: I believe @GramThanos' answer should fix your problem, but to be sure we understand the problem: what do you mean by `when I come to terminate it, it does not always work`? Do you just type `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+Z` into your terminal?

Answer (score 2):

`CTRL + C` sends an SIGINT signal to the active program and the program you are trying to terminate is not the active program at the time.

In such cases I like to save the process id in a file and later kill the process with with that process id.

To do so, I create 2 files, a `start.sh` and a `stop.sh`. I start my script using `start.sh` and stop it using the `stop.sh`

The `start.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting my script..."
nohup python /link/to/script.py > /link/to/script.process.log 2>&1&
echo $! > /link/to/script.process.pid
echo "My script is now running."
```

The `stop.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Stopping my script..."
kill -9 `cat /link/to/script.process.pid`
echo "My script is now stopped."
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only Python script you have running try

`sudo killall python`

or in extreme cases

`sudo killall -9 python`

You would need to give details of your script to know why ctrl-c sometimes works.

Comment: I have tried both of those commands and the script continues to run and does not exit.

Comment: You will need to add the script to your question.

Comment: Just added it now.